# Maven: How can I get a profile to inherit the dependencyManagement tag from a parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, wsgen

I run [wsgen](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html) in its own profile because I don't want it to run every time I build the product.  But I'm getting an error about a missing version when I run it:

> $ mvn package -P wsgen [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] The
>   build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR]   The
>   project project-ejb:2.3.15-SNAPSHOT
>   (C:\Projects\MyProject\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]
>   'build.plugins.plugin[org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version'
>   for org.glassfish:javax.javaee:jar is missing. @ line 167, column 41
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

This is a snippet of the child pom (the pom with the profile):

```
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<parent>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <version>2.3.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wsgen</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <executions>
...
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.javaee</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

But, in the parent pom I'm defining this dependency with its version under the `dependencyManagement` tag.

I think what's happening is the profile doesn't inherit the parent's `dependencyManagement` tag so it thinks that the dependency is missing a version number.  Is there a way to make the profile inherit this from the parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dependencyManagement` applies for `dependencies` in the **pom and child poms**. It does not apply to `dependencies` in **plugins** (at least, that's what i noticed in several plugins, like maven-dependency-plugin).

A possible solution is defining a property (`javax.javaee.version`) in your parent pom and using it in your `dependencyManagement` and in your **jaxws-maven-plugin plugin**.

Comment: I think you're right, because when I defined a dependencyManagement tag directly under the profile, the error didn't change.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [<pluginManagement>](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) tag to configure a plugin in a parent pom, let it be its version number, phase, goal or other configuration.

All inheriting poms will have the same configuration as the parent pom, as long as you declare the same `<groupId>` and `<artifactId>` in child poms.

Comment: But, if what @asgoth says is true, I'd still end up using a variable for the version, right?

Comment: @DanielKaplan You can, but it is not required. Take a look at the example in the link above. As can be seen, there is no `<version>` tag for the maven-jar-plugin in the child pom (neither a hardcoded value, nor a maven property).

Comment: The child avoids the version, but the parent needs the version. Both the parent pom's `<pluginManagement>` and `<dependencyManagement>` would use the same dependency, I'd end up using a variable to avoid a DRY violation.  At least as far as I can tell.